# RecycleView выводит только один элемент

Tags: java, android, массивы, recycleview

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой вот траблой: после создания List'а с данными, загона его в адаптер и использования его в RecycleView список отображается, но отображается лишь первый элемент. С чем это может быть связано? Код приведён ниже

**Функция-парсер.** Работает с элементами класса OneMessage, чьи главные характерристики это позиция (начинается с единицы, получают через функция getPos() )    и текст (получают функцией getText() )

```
 ArrayList<OneMessage> messages_its;
    //парсер сообщений для  ListView
    void parser(OneMessage[] its, OneMessage[] your) {
       OneMessage allcombine[] = new OneMessage[its.length+your.length];
        if (its != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < its.length; i++) {
                if (its[i].getPos()-1 == i) {
                    allcombine[i]=new OneMessage(its[i].getPicture(),its[i].getText(),42,its[i].getVoice_text(),its[i].getFile(),its[i].getVoice(),its[i].getFilereso(),Color.rgb(12,230,45));
                   Log.i("SIZE", String.valueOf(allcombine.length));
                }

            }
            Log.i("Он отправил сообщений", new String(String.valueOf(its.length)));

        }
        if(your!=null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < your.length; i++) {
                if (your[i].getPos()-1 == i)
                    allcombine[i]=new OneMessage(your[i].getPicture(),your[i].getText(),42,your[i].getVoice_text(),your[i].getFile(),your[i].getVoice(),your[i].getFilereso(),Color.rgb(123,24,90));
                    //messages_its.add(new OneMessage(your[i].getPicture(),your[i].getText(),42,null,null,null,null,3200456));
            }
            Log.i("Ты отправил сообщений",new String(String.valueOf(your.length)));
            Log.i("Пример сообщения:",its[0].getText());
            Log.i("ТЫ СЛАЛ",your[0].getText());
        }
        messages_its =new ArrayList<OneMessage>(Arrays.asList(allcombine));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        MessageAdapter messageadapter = new MessageAdapter(this,messages_its);

if(messages_its!=null)  Log.i("SIZE",String.valueOf(messages_its.size()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(messageadapter);
        Log.i("SETED", "SUCCESFULL");

    }
```

**Код адаптера**

```
package com.example.sttmmessenger;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MessageAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<OneMessage> phones;

    MessageAdapter(Context context, List<OneMessage> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_messages, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            OneMessage phone = phones.get(position);
        if(phone!=null){
            holder.textpartview.setText(phone.getText());
            holder.textpartview.setBackgroundColor(phone.getCol());
            Log.i("TEXT", phone.getText());
        }
    }

    public int getItemCount(){
        return phones.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView textpartview;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textpartview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Код самого элемента списка (XML-разметка)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F1FDFB"
            android:focusable="auto"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Который день маюсь с этой проблемой, всё не получается её решить. Причем поведение всегда разное, то показывается элемент массива its, то элемент массива your. Если смотреть по логам, все данные приходят, все длины соблюдены.  .Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь

PS парсер работает по следующему принципу: есть собственно 2 массива, в каждом сообщения от каждой из сторон. Циклом гоняем, если i равна позиции сообщения - 1 (так как позиции начинаются с единицы), то пишем в i-ю ячейку общего массива данные из соответствующей ячейки массива. Не может быть такого, что 2 разных сообщения имеют одну позицию, отчего и можно так заполнять один

PS 2: вот то, что приходит с севера. показывается, что такое pos

```
{
  "status": "SUC",
  "Your": [
    {
      "picture": null,
      "text": "Привет! Как дела7",
      "pos": 1,
      "voice_text": "none",
      "file": null,
      "voice": "nil",
      "filereso": null
    },
    {
      "picture": null,
      "text": "zaebumba!",
      "pos": 3,
      "voice_text": "none",
      "file": null,
      "voice": "nil",
      "filereso": null
    },
    {
      "picture": null,
      "text": "rad za tebia",
      "pos": 4,
      "voice_text": "none",
      "file": null,
      "voice": "nil",
      "filereso": null
    }
  ],
  "its": [
    {
      "picture": null,
      "text": "да нормально всё, в общем)",
      "pos": 2,
      "voice_text": "none",
      "file": null,
      "voice": "nil",
      "filereso": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить по какому принципу формируется список в парсере? Сейчас у вас получается если its != null и your != null то сначала запишуться элементы массива its, а после поверх них запишутся элементы массива your.

Comment: А еще маленькое замечание. Вот это действие `its.length+your.length` кинет Вам NPE, так что дальнейшие проверки на `null` несколько странно выглядят. Пометьте оба параметра аннотацией `@NotNull` и живите счастливо

Comment: парсер работает по следующему принципу: есть собственно 2 массива, в каждом сообщения от каждой из сторон. Циклом гоняем, если i равна позиции сообщения - 1, то пишем в i-ю ячейку данные из соответствующего массива. Не может быть такого, что 2 разных сообщения имеют одну позицию, отчего и можно так заполнять один общий массив:

Comment: @ЕгорПриставка два разных сообщения из двух разных массивов очень даже могут иметь одинаковые позиции.

Comment: @ЕгорПриставка То есть вы имеете ввиду, что позиции получаемые через getPos() в массиве its всегда будут отличаться от таких же позиций в массиве your?

Comment: Так у вас отображается только один элемент всегда, сколько бы их не было или отображаются несколько, но не все?

Comment: Раньше отображались только элементы, взятые из массива its. Теперь вообще отображается только ОДИН элемент. А позиции, получаемые через getPos() одинаковыми быть не могут. Позиция сообщения рассчитывается на сервере и это не просто номер элемента, это свойство элемента класса OneMessage, так что не может получиться такого, что у сообщения из массива its позиция совпадает с поз-й сообщения из массива your

Comment: @ЕгорПриставка Смотрите, согласно вашего же примера. В массиве its позиции у элементов 1, 3, 4. В массиве your 2. В первом цикле вы сравниваете первый элемент 0 == 1-1, добавляем. Второй элемент 1 == 3-1 не добавляем, Третий элемент 2 == 4-1 не добавляем. В следующем цикле первый элемент 0 == 2-1 не добавляем. Вот и выходит 1 элемент на два списка

Comment: К тому же вся эта логика кажется излишней. Достаточно сразу добавлять в allcombine[its[i].getPos() - 1] сообщение для каждого массива. Так же, как вам указали выше, вот этот код its.length+your.length может выкинуть NullPointerException так как проверка массива на null выполняется после.

Comment: Спасибо, blind.falcon! Всё заработало!